# An English translation of Cauchy's "Cours d'Analyse"

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, translations

I am quite interested in the origins of our modern way of understanding analysis. I know that Augustin-Louis Cauchy was one of the pioneers regarding a rigorous foundation towards real and complex analysis, and further he is one of my favorite mathematicians. Therefore I would like to study his original works. The book I am especially interested in is called "Cours d'analyse de l'École royale polytechnique". It is not hard to find these notes in French (they are linked on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy#Output) of Cauchy for example) but hence I am not capable of reading and understanding French this does not help me at all. Honestly speaking, I have no clue how to search for a translation, which source I can trust and so on.

> Therefore I would ask first of all if you are aware of a complete English translation? I am rather sure that something similar to this exists hence the importance of Cauchy and his work within the history of analysis is crucial. Furthermore, could you provide a source where I could - in the best case - directly download the whole papers for example in the form of a PDF or - in the worst case - where I could at least buy a PDF or printed version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seems to be a 2009 Springer translation by Bradley and Sandifer, linked by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse

Comment: I am very surprised that someone cared to translate it. In general, if you want to study history of mathematics seriously (from primary sources) you should learn the principal European languages.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Is it like this in general? I thought that  - since English is the language of science today - at least the important papers were translated to English.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA this is the same as kimchi lover already linked but nevertheless thanks.

Comment: @mrtaurho: yes. I would say that less than 1% of important classical (19 century) work in mathematics is translated into English from German and French, even less from Italian and Russian. Also often these translations are inadequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, 
there seems to be a 2009 [Springer translation](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441905482) by Bradley and Sandifer, linked by a different Wikipedia article